# HTML variables to Python file

Tags: python, html, webserver, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am building a remote control car using the Raspberry Pi, and it runs off of a Python script perfectly from an ssh keyboard input. I want it to be able to run off of a phone's gyroscope. I created an Apache web server and used the source code from this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/deviceorientationsample.html to try and get the gyroscope information. I am correctly receiving the input on the web page and it is displaying/ moving the image properly. I now need to export the 3 variables to a python script that I am running on the same Raspberry Pi. I don't know where to begin as to what to use to export these variables across the two platforms. Also the variables need to be able to update every 10ms. I don't know if this is the best way to set this up or if using something like Node.js would be easier? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Interesting setup.  Just to make sure I understand the architecture... currently, the web browser is running on the phone and hitting the RPi's web server to get the HTML and now you need a way to get the browser to send the gyroscope information to your RPi?

Comment: The phone is running the web browser, but the webserver is actually hosted on the raspberry pi in the same directory as the python file I am trying to send the information to. I need a bridge from the webserver to the python file.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to skin this, although many might have more latency than you'd like (10ms should be a reasonable goal though i don't know enough about the phone side to know if it generates data at that rate) but the challenge will be getting the data off the phone, presumably over a wireless link to the RPi, and then processed in a timely fashion.  An advanced method with lower latencies (which I'm not going to try to write here) would use something like node.js with web sockets listen for updates from the web page (which then requires modifying the webpage code to use websockets) and also do whatever your python script is doing.  A quicker, dirtier, but pure python solution (plus a little javascript) would look something like:

1. Configure apache to use cgi
2. Drop the following code in your cgi-bin directory

> ```
> import socket
> import cgi
>
> form = cgi.FieldStorage
> x = form["x"]
> y = form["y"]
> z = form["z"]
> s = socket.socket()
> s.connect(("localhost",5000))
> s.send(",".join([x,y,z]))
> print "Content-Type: text/text"     
> print                               
> print "Debug: sent",x,y,z
> ```

3. In your javascript code, use jquery to, every 10 milliseconds make a request to http:///cgi-bin/dumpdata.cgi?x=&y=&z= (or whatever values you want to pass through.
   EDIT to add ajax example:
   Assuming you used the sample code you linked to, somewhere inside the  tag, add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>` (or download jquery and run on your webserver, which might be preferable if you're going to run everything over wifi)

   In your `<body>`, optionally create a <`div id="debug">Waiting for response</div>`

   And then in the **deviceOrientationHandler** function, you should be able to do something like

> ```
>   url = "/cgi-bin/dumpdata.cgi?x="+tiltLR+"&y="+tiltFB+"&z="+dir;
> $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
>         //result will hold the results passed back by the CGI
>         $("#debug").html(result);
>     }});
> ```

4. In your python script (which I'm assuming has an event loop), have it do something like:

> ```
>    import socket
>    s = socket.socket()
>    s.bind(("",5000))
>    s.listen(5)
>    while True:
>       cli,addr = s.accept()
>       x,y,z = cli.recv(1000).split(",")
>       print "DEBUG",x,y,z
>       cli.close()
>       # do the rest of your loop
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I configured apache to use cgi and then I put the #2 code in a file called dumpdata.cgi. Afterwards I attempted to write the javascript but I couldn't figure out how to get the jquery setup? Do you think you could point me in the right direction for that?

Comment: See inline edit; note that this is a totally glued together with duct tape and baling wire solution so that you can get something going quickly; I would strongly encourage you to look into websockets etc. once you have the basic setup working

Comment: Also note that as mentioned, I have no idea what the data rate for updates; you might find that deviceOrientationHandler gets called at a rate higher than 100 Hz (which is presumably what you want if you want updates every 10 ms), in which case you probably will want to add some extra logic.  Also realized using TCP was a bit unnecessary... swapping out TCP for UDP sockets would also be a good intermediary step.

Comment: I looked into the websocket connection and found myself way over my head (the most advanced programming language I know is python) I was thinking and the whole program that I am trying to run is to build a GUI, but if I am using the HTML as a gui do you think an approach like this would work and then have certain python scripts turn wheels forward and reverse, etc. http://raspberrywebserver.com/gpio/piface/building-a-remote-control-vehicle-using-a-raspberry-pi.html Also I was wondering if there was a direct way to interface with the gpio pins from html?

Comment: Matt: we're now close to or at the point where a moderator should probably step in and say go to chat.  I would suggest raising the gpio from html as a separate question.  (AFAIK no, especially when the server is on one platform and the browser is on another, but you could certainly do the ajax to cgi-bin mechanism for prototyping)